# cosmos db support different schema in a collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to write a record with a different schema to an existing collection with records . I don't get a exception, but i don't see the new record.
Do I need to use a different collection?

```
       DocumentDBRepository<ScheduleViewModel>.CreateItemAsync(task).GetAwaiter();
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a record that does work and one that currently doesn't? I presume the new record is including the relevant fields e.g. a partition key?

Comment: you can create a record without a partition key in cosmos db even if the collection has partition key set, so that *shoudln't* be a problem

Comment: @4c74356b41 hmm, that's news to me, I could've sworn this previously wasn't allowed.

Comment: i had the same impression, but it works

Comment: @4c74356b41 yep I gave it a go myself, not sure how that works, I guess Cosmos must just create a `null` logical partition.

Comment: yeah, there's a hidden logical partition for those

Comment: @4c74356b41 This used to be the default behavior but the CosmosDB team is now trying to move people away from it, that's why you can't find it in the portal anymore (it used to be there). It doesn't have to do with logical partitions per se but rather a single physical one.

Comment: You do not have to use different collections for different schemas since CosmosDB is a schemaless NoSQL database. This is exactly how collection sharing in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) works.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB doesn't care about what you put into to it (as almost any other nosql db), so this is supported from the Cosmos DB perspective. from the code perspective, I suppose you need to create a connection that would support the model your are using and create a document

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Are you suggesting that I create a separate collection for different schema ?

Comment: what, where'd you read that? no, you can put any documents in the same collection